# Oracle - why do none of the provided regexs work?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have tried multiple regexs from [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) and none of them work correctly. Example:

```
declare
  v_result integer;
  v_link nvarchar2(300) := 'http://example.com/blah_blah/';
  v_regexp nvarchar2(300) := '@^(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$@iS';
begin
  begin
    select 1 into v_result
    from dual
    where regexp_like(v_link, v_regexp);
  exception when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line('false');
      return;
  end;
  dbms_output.put_line('true');
end;
```

This returns false, although it should return true. Why?

Comment: None of those regular expressions are going to work in Oracle as they do not use the same regular expression syntax that Oracle does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex pattern appears to be taken from some source which requires formal delimiters in the pattern.  This is not required in Oracle, and in fact your leading/trailing `@` will match this literal character.  Also, if you want to use `REGEXP_LIKE` in case insensitive mode, you should pass `'i'` as the third parameter flag, rather than using `@i` appended to the end of the pattern.

Also note that the pattern itself had problems.  You probably intended the first character class to be `+`, one or more.  And also, the literal dot separating the domain from the ending needs to be escaped with backslash.  Finally, if you want to express whitespace *inside* a character class, you should be using `[:space:]`, not `\s`, the latter which will be interpreted as literal character `s`.  Taking all this into account, consider this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(url, '^(https?|ftp)://[^[:space:]/$.?#]+\.[^[:space:]]*$', 'i');
```

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'http://example.com/blah_blah/' AS url FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'http://test.com' FROM dual
)
```

### Demo

Comment: Removing delimiters solved some of the issues. However, regardless if your modifications (+ and \\) are added or not, `https://www.example.com` returns true, but if 'example' is substituted with other random words like 'test' or 'something' it returns false. Isn't [^..] meant to exclude characters in the brackets?

Comment: @vr552 Good catch, I think you want `[:space:]` inside your character class, not `\s`.  Check the update, which now matches the `test` URL (it wasn't matching before because the domain name had `s` in it).

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions in Oracle do not support:

- Characters prefixing the regular expression (many of the examples on the page you link start with `@`, `#`, `~` or `_`). Similarly, Oracle does not support the same characters as suffixes. These appear to be specific to certain parsers/languages and are not standard regular expression syntax.
- Flags (i.e. case-insensitivity) embedded at the beginning or end of the regular expression (many examples end with `@iS` or start with `(?i)`). This would need to be passed as a parameter to the regular expression matching function you are using rather than being embedded in the regualr expression string.
- Perl-like patterns inside character set matches (In Oracle, `[^\s]` would match any character that is not `\` or `s` when the intent is to match any character that is not a space character matched by the Perl-style `\s` expression; this needs to be translated to the POSIX expression `[^[:space:]]`).
- Non-capturing groups (Oracle does not support `(?: )` and would need to be converted to a capturing group `( )`).
- Word boundaries (Oracle does not support `\b`. There is no replacement syntax that can be used; you just need to remove these from the regular expression).
- Look ahead (Oracle does not support `(?= )`. Again, there is no replacement for this syntax; you either need to find an equivalent construct without look-ahead or cannot use the regular expressions that rely on this).
- Escaped `-` or `]` characters in character set matches. (In Oracle, you would need to use `[]a-z-]` with the `]` character as the first character in the character set and the `-` as the last character in the character set rather than using `[a-z\-\]]` where `\` is used to escape those characters).

There may be more that is not supported but you would need to correct all these issues to fix the regular expressions.

Comment: `Word boundaries ... There is no replacement syntax` ... perhaps so, but we can get close using `(^| )some_word( |$)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is so much more that `\b` looks for (including punctuation, brackets, other white-space, etc.) plus it is a zero-width match when your replacement is not. Also, some of those regular expressions have `\b` scattered through-out the expression (at least one uses it to match the end of the TLD) and looking for `( |$)` at those points would give the regular expression an entirely different meaning.